# I don't want nautilus to show my NFS share as "umountable" when only root can umount it

Tags: nautilus, mount, fstab, nfs, eject

`/etc/fstab`

```
192.168.0.14:/media/hdd500         /mnt/sosonicoco      nfs user,auto 0 0
192.168.0.14:/media/hdd500/Musique /home/nicoco/Musique nfs user,auto 0 0
```

`sosonicoco` is seen by nautilus as a normal directory, but `Musique` appears as a umountable device, even though I have an error message stating I need root privileges to umount it when I click its `eject` button.

How can I avoid nautilus to list this `Musique` mounted NFS directory here?

It also appears in Unity launcher, which is even more annoying

Answer (score 1):

From the `mount` man page:

```
The non-superuser mounts.
       Normally,  only  the  superuser can mount filesystems.  However,
       when fstab contains the user option on a line, anybody can mount
       the corresponding system.

       Thus, given a line

              /dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide

       any  user  can  mount  the iso9660 filesystem found on his CDROM
```

As you've set the `user` option for those mounts in `/etc/fstab`, they are mountable/unmountable by ordinary users.  If you remove that option, then Nautilus shouldn't consider those volumes user unmountable.

Comment: thanks, I was just confused by the fact that the other share, with the same options, didn't appear